# Next Formula result based on previous Formula Result SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to calculate in between LAT values of records 14-23.

Here's an example:

```
Id  LAT             ODO
13  30.85629535     33.95
14              33.95
15              36.32
16              36.57
17              38.69
18              39.63
19              39.87
20              41.22
21              41.62
22              44.6
23              46.21
24  30.85633529     48.38
```

Assuming that we are on Record 14, then previous means the value previous to record 14.  Current means the current 14 record value, Next is the Next available from the current record.

```
(NextAvailableLat - PrevLat) * ((CurrentODO - PrevODO) / 
(NextAvailableODO - PrevODO)) + PrevLat

(30.85633529 - 30.85629535) * ((33.95 - 33.94) / (48.38 - 33.94)) + 30.85629535
```

When I get to record 15, my formula would need to retain the previous calculated LAT in order to calculate the new Lat

I have tried with a cursor in which I pass the ID and this works fine, however when I get to large datasets it takes a really long time.  Some batches have close to 1M records which drags for hours.  I was hoping for a update statement...but I can't figure out how to retain that previous calculated value.

I have an update wrapped in a cursor.  The cursor passes the ID

This is the expected results:

```
Id  LAT          ODO
13  30.85629535 33.95
14  30.85629535 33.95
15  30.85630191 36.32
16  30.8563026  36.57
17  30.85630847 38.69
18  30.85631107 39.63
19  30.85631173 39.87
20  30.85631547 41.22
21  30.85631658 41.62
22  30.85632483 44.6
23  30.85632929 46.21
24  30.85633529 48.38
```

Script to insert data:

```
    CREATE table dbo.Lats
    (ID int
    , LAT decimal(14,8)
   ,ODO decimal(10,2))


    INSERT INTO  dbo.Lats
    select * from (
   select 13 ID,     30.85629535 LAT,   33.95 ODO
   union
   select 14,   null,       33.95
   union
  select 15,    null,       36.32
  union
  select 16,    null,       36.57
  union
  select 17,    null,       38.69
  union
  select 18,    null,       39.63
  union
  select 19,    null,       39.87
  union
  select 20,    null,       41.22
  union
  select 21,    null,       41.62
   union
  select 22,    null,       44.6
  union
  select 23,    null,       46.21
  union
  select 24,    30.85633529 ,48.38) lats
   order by ID
```

Below is a While loop that I used to get the results:

```
    declare @minid  int ,@maxid int, @currentID int
   set @minid =13
   set @maxid = 24
   set @currentID = 14

    WHILE @currentID <@maxid
   BEGIN  
 DECLARE @NextLat decimal(14,8) , @PrevLat decimal(14,8) , @PrevODO  decimal(10,2) , @CurrentODO decimal(10,2) , @NextODO decimal(10,2)

     select @NextLat = LAT from  dbo.Lats where id = @maxid
     select @PrevLat = LAT from  dbo.Lats where id = @currentID - 1
     select @PrevODO = odo from  dbo.Lats where id = @currentID - 1  
     select @CurrentODO = odo from  dbo.Lats where id =@currentID
     select @NextODO = odo from  dbo.Lats where id =@maxid 

       update dbo.Lats
       set LAT = ((@NextLat - @PrevLat) * ((@CurrentODO - @PrevODO)         (@NextODO - @PrevODO)) + @PrevLat)
       from dbo.Lats
       where ID = @currentID

      set @currentID = @currentID + 1

      END
```

Comment: Why do ids "14" and "23" duplicate the end points.

Comment: Hi Gordon, they are odometers so it's possible that they can be very close to each other

Comment: . . You are imputing in-between values and these are no in-between.  They are at the ends.

Comment: I am trying to calculate for records 14-23.